# How does google chrome determine where auto saved passwords should be inserted on web pages?

Tags: javascript, php, html, google-chrome

Running into a strange problem on google chrome.  The short version is that my site will allow google chrome to save a password if the user chooses.  On another page, there is the option to change some settings as well as change the password.  The password change is actually a jquery light box form and not showed, however there are hidden feilds as placeholders for the password if the light box is used.  Somehow, google chrome is inserting that password in the hidden field automatically and it's causing the form to fail authentication as a confirmation password is not entered for the new password.

How is google chrome deciding which inputs to autofill passwords in?

Comment: I'd guess it checks the input `name` attributes? However, please show the sample code you're using for the login, the hidden fields and the light box form.

Comment: Please show the login form HTML and the hidden field

Comment: Definitely not the name attribute, I was maybe thinking the input type?  I really am at a loss on this one, it shouldn't be doing it, it doesn't do it in any other browser.

Comment: Add `autocomplete="off"` to the password fields that it's breaking

Answer (score 0):

It checks input types and names. Add `autocomplete="off"` as attribute to avoid Google Chrome filling in a password.